# Saving the content of large .txt file into variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, append

I have a huge .txt file containing approx 100m lines, and I want to save its content into a list line by line.

I'm using the following code to achive this:

```
tmp=[]
with open('xy.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        tmp.append(line)
```

Now the problem with this, that this code doesn't release the memory until the whole file is read, thus after a while it runs out of memory.

My question is, that is there any way of completing this task memory efficiently?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the list variable `tmp`?

Comment: I want to postprocess the data in the txt file, that's why I wanted to store it in a list.

Comment: Yes, but do you need all 100m entries at the same time? That is, does the processing of one entry depend on others? Or do you process them one by one independently?

Comment: Actually I only need part of, let's say from 2m to 10m.

Comment: Then you should selectively add the entries to the list based on the said condition. Moreover, if the postprocessing of each entry does not involve cross-referencing other entries at arbitrary indices, you can avoid creating a list by processing each entry directly in the loop.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that all of the selected entries are required for postprocessing. The answer with the yield solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a generator that yields line by line:

```
def gen():
    with open('xy.txt') as fh:
        yield from fh
```

If you need only a specific part of it, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to select that slice:

```
import itertools as it

data = it.islice(gen(), 10**6, 10**7)
```

Comment: The file object is already an iterable. There is absolutely no need to make a generator for it.

Comment: @blhsing The purpose of the generator is to hold the `with` block, but sure you could just copy & paste that into the "main" part of the code.